# Separate string as delimiter strtok (C++)

Tags: c++

I have a text
I need to find in each proposal max word and min word.(Separated by dots)
I wrote a function to find it.
I'm trying to send first separated proposal to a function

```
calculateString(token);
```

.
After this variable token is truncated.
Thanks for answers!

Updated:
Question:I need to found in each proposal max and min text.On the first step it's truncated.How can I avoid it?(Do not truncate after using it) –

Code:

```
//Output/input /cin/cout
#include <iostream>
//System libary
#include <cstdlib>

//include printf/sprintf/scanf
#include <stdio.h>

//include string libary
#include <string>

//
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void calculateString(char *str){
    char *temp;
    int len;
    int i = 0;
    char** stringArray;
    string long_word,short_word;

    temp = strtok(str," ,.!?");
    cout << "Str:" <<  str << "\n";
    int string_count = 0;//counting first word in string. 
    int string_count_short = 0;
      stringArray = new char*[string_count];
        while(temp = strtok(NULL," ,.!?"))
        {
                //cout << "\n" << temp << "\n";
                len = strlen(temp);
                if(len>string_count || string_count == 0){
                    string_count = len;
                    long_word =  temp;
                }
                if(len<string_count_short || string_count_short == 0){
                    string_count_short = len;
                    short_word=  temp; 

                }
        }       
       cout << "Longest word in all text is:" <<  long_word << "\n";
       cout << "Shortest word in all text is:" <<  short_word << "\n";
}
int main()
{
   char str[] = "Hello it's a test.Lets go.How are you?Andrej";
   char seps[]   = ".";

   char *token;
   token = strtok( str, seps );
   while( token != NULL )
   {
      /* While there are tokens in "string" */
      cout << " :: " << token << " ||\n";
      calculateString(token);

      /* Get next token: */
      token = strtok( NULL, seps );
   }
    //calculateString(str);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what's the question? Are you aware that `strtok()` modifies the string it's given? And why the C tag?

Comment: Question:I need to found in each proposal max and min text.On the first step it's truncated.How can I avoid it?(Do not truncate after using it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (this is hack)

```
/*Const string count */
   const int string_count = 10;
   /*Total string found */
   int str_count = 0;
   /* String delimiter*/
   char seps[]   = ".";

   char *token;
   token = strtok( str, seps );

   /* Creating array of chars */
   char** stringArray;
   /* Dynamic array of chars*/
   stringArray = new char*[string_count];

   while( token != NULL )
   {
      /* While there are tokens in "string" */
      stringArray[++str_count] = token; 
      /* Get next token: */
      token = strtok( NULL, seps );
   }
   /* Seperated propsal */
   for(int i=1;i <=str_count;i++){
         calculateString(stringArray[i]);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use `strtok()` in a reentrant fashion, which won't work because `strtok()` keeps a static state. The calls to `strtok()` within `calculateString()` clobber the state from the calls in `main()`.

You might be interested in [`strtok_r()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r). Or better yet, look into something like [Boost.Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/tokenizer/).

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not extremely sensitive in your app, try STL or Boost library, which will free you from the old-fashion issues.

Hope it helps.